# Highcharts legend styling with usehtml

Tags: highcharts, legend

I need to use the pagination of Highcharts (v2.3.5) legend, as my graph use numerous series of data. The thing is I would like to add an image (with a dedicated tooltip) on each legend item, and so use the useHTML property to enable the use of more complex label formats.

The problem is that in that case, the legend overflows the usual frame and goes over the navigation buttons, thus making them unusable. You will find a simple example of this problem here : http://jsfiddle.net/APtZ3/190/

```
 legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 30,
        labelFormatter: function () {return '<span>' + this.name+'</span>';},
        useHTML:true
    },
```

Please let me know if anybody can help me on this.

Note: the problem was to be solved with highcharts new version, but it was not (see http://dev.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=22192&p=86900&hilit=legend+navigation#p86900 )

Comment: Yes, looks like bug strikes again! Added report: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1249